# External JS file - Event Listener

Tags: javascript

I have an external JS file that is loaded correctly.

I have a function inside that file, that adds an event listener on a button.

I also have inside that file, the function that is supposed to be invoked when the event is triggered.

So we have: 
HTML

```
<input type="submit" id="subBtn" value="POST ARTICLE">

    <script>
        eventListeners();
    </script>
```

JS file

```
function eventListeners(){
document.getElementById("subBtn").addEventListener("click",newContent); }
```

newContent() is also inside the JS file

This fails.

I have noticed however, that when i place the event listener on the input like so:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="newContent();" value="POST ARTICLE">
```

It works.

Why? And how do i correct myself?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the JavaScript file included?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your eventListeners() call to the body onload function. If this works then your script is firing before the element is loaded into the document.

Something like this --

```
<body onLoad="eventListeners();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you including your JS file? If you are including it before the element itself, it cannot add the the event listener because the element has not been loaded yet. It's usually best practice to include the scripts at the very end of the body. It's also wise to make the JS wait until the document has loaded before adding in event handlers like so:

```js
function newContent(){
    // function
}

function eventListeners(){
    document.getElementById("subBtn").addEventListener("click",newContent);
}

// Wait until the document is ready
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    eventListeners();
});
```